# ng-repeat more time to load the huge data

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

We are using AngularJS 1.4.3 and `ng-repeat` to load an array of objects.

When the array length is more than 800 records, `ng-repeat` takes more time to load. Sometimes it's not able to load the page.

We tried with `vs-repeat`, though it did not help.

Do we have any other modules/directives for loading such huge data in AngularJS?

Comment: Huge data is when you have 10000+ records. You can try to remove the watchers with one-time binding, reducing the lag: `<div ng-repeat="rec in ::records">{{::rec}}</div>`

Comment: this project has been development for 4-5 years. So, We can't change it to angular-2. Do we have any suggestions for angular-1 ??

Comment: @AlekseySolovey we are doing the same. But somehow this is not reducing the loading time

Comment: @MaharjunM then it's not the source of lag. Can you show your code? Maybe you can find the issue in "Network" / "Performance" tabs of the developer console, checking for the load times of various methods

Comment: I didn't say you should change to Angular 2+. I said Angular 1 is slow and heavy, and there's no real way to speed it up, this is why companies dropped it. In other words, no, you can't really speed it up because that's the way it's been made. By design, there's a dirty-checking cycle that eats a lot of processing power.

Comment: I checked the network call time. it is 1.3 min. After that also it is taking more time to load. that data is around 1.1MB. It is able to assign the data. But not able to load it in the view.

Comment: Try virtualRepeat of Angularjs Material (https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/virtualRepeat). It's intresting... display a list of 50,000 items that load on demand in a viewport of only 7 rows.